# file_get_contents() problem, works fine in Local not in server

Tags: php

I am trying to send an SMS using an API.

Using `file_get_contents()`, the message is sent sucessfully from my local machine, but it's not working on my server. I get this warning:

```
Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname in /usr/home/....
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please show your code. It looks like it's interpreting `/usr/home` as a hostname somehow, which cannot be correct.

Comment: No, that's the filename.

Answer (score 1):

Many (free or cheap) shared-hosting providers forbid server-to-server requests, so you can't do:

```
file_get_contents('http://some.external.io/request');
```

You may be able to circumvent this using cURL, stream/fopen functions, or other extensions, but you shouldn't count on it... get a better host if you want to do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a web host which does not allow file operations. This is quite common on some non-dedicated hosting services.

Comment: Can any one help me any other way to solve this,i mean other than this method,working properly on all servers

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using the IP of the domain and it was successful
Like:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://1.1.1.11/');
```

Used IP of my domain.